# How to change application icon from other application

Tags: android

I want to change application icon of another application from my application how can we do this.I want to see all the applications that are listed and can change icon of one application

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't give any such type of permission where you can change the other application icon from your app. So it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

From [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) page:

> Once installed on a device, each Android app lives in its own security sandbox:
>
> - The Android operating system is a multi-user Linux system in which each app is a different user.
> - By default, the system assigns each app a unique Linux user ID (the ID is used only by the system and is unknown to the app). The system sets permissions for all the files in an app so that only the user ID assigned to that app can access them.
> - Each process has its own virtual machine (VM), so an app's code runs in isolation from other apps.
> - By default, every app runs in its own Linux process. Android starts the process when any of the app's components need to be executed, then shuts down the process when it's no longer needed or when the system must recover memory for other apps.

But there is an exception to that:

> It's possible to arrange for two apps to share the same Linux user ID, in which case they are able to access each other's files. To conserve system resources, apps with the same user ID can also arrange to run in the same Linux process and share the same VM (the apps must also be signed with the same certificate).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    **<application android:icon="@drawable/images"** android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidVideoPlayer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Videopage"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```